# Get private_ip_address Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, cloud, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I am writing a terraform code for virtual machine scale set, in which I need Private IP Address as output.
Earlier code was virtual machine based and I was able to get the private_ip_address output from the NIC.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "test" {
  name                = "${local.name}"
  location            = local.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name

  # automatic rolling upgrade
  automatic_os_upgrade = false
  upgrade_policy_mode  = "Manual"
  sku {
    name     = var.vm_size
    tier     = "Standard"
    capacity = 1
  }

 storage_profile_image_reference {
   id = data.azurerm_shared_image_version.image.id
 }

  storage_profile_os_disk {
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name_prefix = "${local.name}"
    admin_username       = <username>
    admin_password        = <password>
    custom_data     = base64encode(data.template_file.cloud_init.rendered)
  }

  network_profile {
    name    = "${local.name}-nic-1"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name                                   = "ip"
      primary                                = true
      subnet_id                              = module.subnet.id
    }
  }
    network_profile {
    name    = "${local.name}-nic-2"
    primary = false
    ip_configuration {
      name                                   = "ip"
      primary                                = true
      subnet_id                              = module.subnet.id
    }
  }

  tags = local.tags
}
```

> Not able to get the IPs in network profile output.
> azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.test.network_profile
>
> it does not include private_ip_address of vmss.
>
> So, is there any way to get the private IP Address of VMSS?

Comment: It appears only public IPs may be accessible for this in Azure. I believe the assumption is these are placed behind a Load Balancer with an associated public IP, or have associated public IPs themselves.

Comment: we don't want to add public ip in our case, private ip has to be pass to cloud-init as variable. alternative would be to get the ip from the system via ifconfig but that also not the case, or to get it with az cli, but we can not put az cli in the VM. any other option?